# Soft: Applications of Entire Functions to Probability Theory

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, complex-numbers, characteristic-functions

What are some applications of entire functions to probability theory?

For example, I know many random variables' characteristic function can be extended to a certain strip of the complex plane, but I've never seen any extension theorems to all of $\mathbb{C}$ itself.

Comment: I think $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k e^{kx} = \psi(x)$ is a break down of the solutions to the dirac delta potential form of the Schrodinger Equation. $ . I think those are all entire and generally able to represent arbtrary functions by the generalized Stone-Weirstrass theorem.

Answer (score 1):

An example that comes to mind is Cramer's decomposition theorem:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent so that $X + Y$ is a normal random variable, then both $X$ and $Y$ are normal.

The standard proof is by entire functions.  See [these notes](https://homepages.uc.edu/~brycwz/probab/charakt/charakt.pdf)  for a proof, and more references to the use of entire functions.

Comment: This is interesting, but I was looking for a "general use/method" and not only a specific case.